# VB.Net - Buttons missing on one client

Tags: vb.net

We're facing a strange problem here. One of our users cannot see two buttons on a form, that everybody else can see. I'm not sure if the buttons are not there or the window is smaller than it should be. The size of this window is fixed, so it cannot be adjusted manually. (it is like a pop-up window informt of the main window)

Our application is used by employees of our company all over the world. So they all have windows xp in different languages and their regional settings differ. But I can't see how that would make a difference.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: All of your clients are up-to-date using the same .NET libraries and service packs?

Comment: Not necessarily. I will check that.

Comment: Ask about what virus scanners they have running. It sounds ridiculous, but some of them do inexplicable things to applications.

Comment: I had a user with this same problem the other day.  Part of their form was scrolled outside of the visible bounds of the screen.

Comment: @briddums: This would be a realy nice solution to solve this. Resize the screen settings... :D

Comment: Sounds like someone is running at 800x600

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reason for this might be that the user changed the DPI setting on its machine. Typically you would change that in the control panel, in the Display settings you can choose to have a font size of 100%, 125% and 150%. This affects the DPI and might push winforms controls further down the form, making them "invisible" (below the bottom boundary of the form).

[Here are instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/display_use_large_or_small_fonts.mspx?mfr=true) on how to change DPI settings on Windows XP.

If this is the cause for your problem, you have to make sure your forms scale properly. Look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for automatic scaling.

Comment: That was it! The user had the DPI set to 120 instead of the normal 96. I tried to set my own DPI to 120 and got the same issue: The buttons were gone. When I went back to 96 DPI everything was fine again. At least I know now what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Make extensive use layout panels to avoid this problem.  I generally use nested `TableLayoutPanels`.  `Labels` and `Buttons` are set to auto size or a fixed size, `ComboBoxes` and `TextBoxes` are set `Anchor = Left, Right`, and larger controls are set `Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right`.  Then I set the table's column and row sizes to `Auto` or `Percentage` as required.